# Scrolling of 10000 divs is pretty slow in Chrome — any ways to speed it up?

Tags: html, performance, browser

I have a page with static 10000 divs (in a column). Scrolling goes pretty slow (fps < 15) in Chrome 65 (Firefox 59 on Servo is OK). `Update Layer Tree` in the profiler consumes most time. Are there any ways to speed it up?

https://jsfiddle.net/Reiser/mn2e9f94/

Comment: you could try not having so many divs on one page... think of it like stackoverflow showing all the questions in history it's not going to work

Comment: I'd suggest pagination if you're throwing that much data on a page.

Comment: Are there any way to use `transition: translateZ(0)` kind of tricks?